# GULP - Merge multiple browserify bundles in one stream

Tags: javascript, gulp, browserify, watchify

i'm working on a big web application. I'm using Gulp to build javascript files and Browserify.

The problem is that when i'm in development mode, it takes so much time to rebuild my javascript bundle each time i make changes (using watch)

For my application, i need to package all javascript files in one file with a special order:

- all vendors files (including bootstrap jquery etc..)
- some files that need to be browserified (using commonJS style on it with 
  `require('...');`)
- some files that need to be browserified and babelified (`.jsx`files)

As i do not want to wast time between files saves waiting for browserify to bundle all files (average 20-25 seconds...), i decided to split the flow with 3 bundles that are built async and then merge all that 3 temporary bundles to one. (in this way, it takes only 15sec for the first build and if i make one change in a file with watchify, it takes only 2 seconds to being rebuilt instead of 20sec).

My problem, is that when i was using only one pipe to bundle the final file, using browserify and `debug: true` option, i had access to all sources files separatly in the chrome developper console, thanks to browserify debug option because there was only one sourcemap file generated.

But now with 3 pipes, each pipe builds its own sourcemap, and when i merge the 3 temp bundles in the final one, with `gulp-sourcemaps`
 plugin and `loadMaps: true`option, an error occured on the web browser console (so the app doesn't works). And if i turn off `debug: true` on browserify options, it works correctly, but i can't debug each JS files separalty. I have only the big 100K lines final file...

Did someone could help me having the correct sourcemap please ?

here is the kind of error thrown

```
if (file.isNull() || file.sourceMap) {
             ^

TypeError: Object (function e(t,n,r){function s(o,u){if(!n[o]){if(!t[o]){var a=typeof require=="function"&&require;if(!u&&a)return a(o,!0);if(i)return i(o,!0);var f=new Error("Cannot find module '"+o+"'");throw f.code="MODULE_NOT_FOUND",f}var l=n[o]={exports:{}};t[o][0].call(l.exports,function(e){var n=t[o][1][e];return s(n?n:e)},l,l.exports,e,t,n,r)}return n[o].exports}var i=typeof require=="function"&&require;for(var o=0;o<r.length;o++)s(r[o]);return s})({ 
has no method 'isNull'
    at DestroyableTransform.sourceMapInit [as _transform] (/space/iadvize.com/Deploy/releases/20151230085529/desk/node_modules/gulp-sourcemaps/index.js:20:14)
```

Due to this error, i can't merge the sourcemaps generated by all browserify bundles.

Comment: I don't think your bundle should take so much time to build. It should take like 100ms if you do it properly because of watchify. Are you with cache and packageCache options active in your bundle options?

Comment: it takes 20s only at the first build, then when watchify runs, it takes around 1-2 s (its really a big app) and yes i provided ```cache: {},
  packageCache: {}```options